# create and open a pdf on a click of link and show print button with react-pdf

Tags: java, reactjs, react-pdf

In my project, I have requirement of creating a pdf with the data , I am getting from Java backend API.

Is it possible to create and open the pdf on click of a button with react-pdf and also show print button on pdf?

I am new to UI development, so if it is possible please let me know any references also.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

On the click button, you will get data and you can pass that data to your pdf component and open pdf viewer

```
import React from 'react';
import { PDFViewer } from '@react-pdf/renderer';
import MyDocument from './MyDocument';

const ViewPDF = () => (
  <PDFViewer>
    <MyDocument />//Component which create pdf 
  </PDFViewer>
);
```

you can use `ViewPDF` component in your component in which you are having a button and you can render it conditionally

Comment: Thank you for quick response, is it possible to open a pdf on click of button/link rather than downloading it? I see,example link you gave is for pdfmake , is it possible to pass in dynamic data

Comment: can you please explain in detail what is your requirement?

Comment: I need to open a pdf document with image,dynamic data and styling on click of button/link.I am using Java as backend and react on front end.Is it possible with any UI library which can work with React?

Comment: I think PDFViewer will render pdf on the same page or will it open pdf in separate window

Comment: if you find the answer helpful, please make it accepeted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218341/discussion-between-dishant-desai-and-khushi).